# Can we change location from US to other region while reading data from Bigquery using Bigquery java library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

I am trying to read data from **Bigquery** using **[Bigquery java library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.96.0)**.

My dataset is not in US location, so when i am giving my dataset name to library , it is throwing an error that dataset not found in US location because it searches by default in US location.

I have also tried giving the location using setLocation("asia-southeast1") but still it is finding in US location.

This is my code snippet:

```
val bigquery: BigQuery =BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setLocation("asia-southeast1").build().getService
val query = "SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t, true) AS json_row FROM "+dbName+"."+tableName+" AS t"
logger.info("Query is " + query)
val queryResult: QueryJobConfiguration = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build
val result: TableResult = bigquery.query(queryResult)
```

I am writing code in SCALA. As it uses same libraries as JAVA and JAVA is more popular, thats why I am asking this for JAVA.

Please help me to know that how I can change location from US to southeast.

Can I change something inside *QueryJobConfiguration* as i have searched a-lot but i am unable to find anything.

My only requirement is that I want final result as TableResult.

This is the exception being thrown

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Not found: Dataset XXXXXXXX was not found in location US
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:106)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getQueryResults(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:584)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$34.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1203)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$34.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1198)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getQueryResults(BigQueryImpl.java:1197)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getQueryResults(BigQueryImpl.java:1181)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job$1.call(Job.java:329)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job$1.call(Job.java:326)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.poll(RetryHelper.java:64)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.waitForQueryResults(Job.java:325)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.getQueryResults(Job.java:291)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.query(BigQueryImpl.java:1168)
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't actually need to specify the location because BigQuery will infer it from the dataset being referenced in your query. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location).

> When loading data, querying data, or exporting data, BigQuery
>   determines the location to run the job based on the datasets
>   referenced in the request. For example, if a query references a table
>   in a dataset stored in the asia-northeast1 region, the query job will
>   run in that region.

I just tested using the Java SDK on a dataset/table I created in `asia-southeast1`, and it worked without needing to explicitly specify the location.

[image]

[image]

If it's still not working for you by default (check the table you're referncing actually exists), then you can specify the location by setting it in the `JobId` and passing that to the overloaded method:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `grey-sort-challenge.asia_southeast1.a_table`;";
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                .setUseLegacySql(Boolean.FALSE)
                .build();

        JobId id = JobId.newBuilder().setLocation("asia-southeast1")
                .setRandomJob()
                .build();
        try {
            for (FieldValueList row : BIGQUERY.query(queryConfig, id).iterateAll()) {
                for (FieldValue val : row) {
                    System.out.printf("%s,", val.toString());
                }
                System.out.printf("\n");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Graham. I was able to solve the problem. Actually, dataset was not there in south east location. When I created it in south east, I was able to solve. Also we need to mention the location as by default it searches in US only. I have verified with Google cloud BQ library. This was the foolish mistake from my side.